# C++ to Java porting code with bitwise operators and unsigned int

Tags: java, c++, porting

I need to translate C++ code to Java. I have two issues I am worried about.

1) Translation of 'unsigned int' from C++ to Java as 'long'.
I choose to use long to increase storage capacity.

2) Use of bitwise operators, specifically | and <<. Given that
I have translate the unsigned int values to long, would this have
any bad effect for these operators? For example in C++:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;
unsigned int c;

a | (b<<c)
```

is it OK to do this in Java:

```
long a, b, c;

a | (b<<c)
```

Please let me know about any issues you think I might encounter
doing these things.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it and checked the result?

Comment: You'll have a wonderful time debugging code when that sign bit turns into a 1 and bites you. Not that you can't do it, but it's much harder to get right than it might seem. Bit manipulation in Java can be a nightmare.

Comment: If `unsigned int` is 32-bit in C++, then `0x40000000 << 2` is zero in C++ but nonzero in Java `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you do is safe and should work well in Java. Bitwise operations used as you show should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`long` is signed in Java.

> The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of
>   9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).

`unsigned int` from C++ is one word long (32-bit on 32-bit machine). It has range from 0 to 4,294,967,295.

Comment: `unsigned int` must be at least 16 bits. Beyond that, compilers can and do vary.

Comment: everything except character is signed in java

Comment: `unsigned int` is implementation defined in C++. (The longest I've actually seen, however, is 48 bits.)

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Remember that Java `long` is 64-bit. The only real difference is that Java integers are signed.

Operators should behave the same as for unsigned:
`+`, `-`, `==`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`

These will change behavior:
`*`, `/`, `%`, `<`

Use `>>>` instead of `>>` to have unsigned interpretation of `/2**k` (bits pushed are `0`, not MSB copies).

Comment: If the values are all originally 32 bit unsigned, they will be positive when placed in a Java `long`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes, you can use `signed long` as such `unsigned int` integers, but then you have to mask out the high part for many operations.

Comment: Which?  Or at least, which operations in which you're not masking already?

Answer (score 1):

```
       Bitwise operations

  It's important to remember that the unsigned keyword affects 
  the interpretation, not the representation of a number. In other 
  words, in cases where we aren't interpreting a value arithmetically— so-called
  bitwise operations such as AND, OR, XOR— it makes essentially no 
  difference whether a value is marked as "signed" or "unsigned"
```

. 
Unsigned int is equivalent to long in java. So, it makes on difference. 
For more information refer [here](http://www.javamex.com/java_equivalents/unsigned.shtml)

Comment: @PeteBecker can you please expand on what misinformation you believe is on that site? As near as I can tell, the info there is solid (with the exception that they aren't super explicit about the fact that different C implementations have different size ints, and that their examples are assuming a 32 bit int)